# Pass variable to template in Airflow

Tags: airflow

In Airflow I am creating branches with different operators with a for loop, my code looks like this:

```
for table in ['messages', 'conversations']:
    Operator1 with operator1.task_id = 'operator1_{}'.format(table)
    Operator1 does kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='file_name', value='y')

    Operator2 is a BashOperator that needs to run:
    bash_command = "echo {{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='operator1_{}', key='file_name') }}".format(table)       

    Operator1 >> Operator2
```

But in the UI the commands are rendered like that:

```
echo { ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='operator1_messages', key='file_name') }
echo { ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='operator1_conversations', key='file_name') }
```

How should I write the bash_command to have Airflow interpret correctly the template?

If I write directly

```
 bash_command = "echo {{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='operator1_messages', key='file_name') }}"
```

it works but I want to create this command from a for loop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doing this because the `.format(table)` part of your bash command is stripping off the outer `{` and `}`. You may be able to fix this with the following instead:

```
bash_command = "echo {{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='operator1_" + table + "', key='file_name') }}"
```

Whether this is the best way to do it is probably another question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now! I also managed to fix it doing

    bash_command = "echo {{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='operator1_ %(table)s', key='file_name') }}" and setting  parameters={'table': table} in Operator2